How can I divide one histogram by another and then plot the results on another?
I have made two histograms, one that has one with the total data provided and another that has only a sample of the data. I'm trying to obtain the fraction of the sampled data compared to the total data, but the resulting histogram doesn't make any sense
The code that I tried using goes as follows:
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, AutoMinorLocator)
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

hdulist = fits.open('./GalCat_lean-1.fits')
tbdata = hdulist[1].data
satellite_mask = tbdata['mass_halo'] == -1.0
sat_data = tbdata[satellite_mask]
central_mask = tbdata['mass_halo'] != -1.0
cen_data = tbdata[central_mask]

sat_z = sat_data.field(3)
cen_z = cen_data.field(3)

sat_masshalo = sat_data.field(0)
cen_masshalo = cen_data.field(0)

sat_Nsat = sat_data.field(6)
cen_Nsat = cen_data.field(6)


mass_halo = tbdata.field(0) 
RA = tbdata.field(1)
Dec = tbdata.field(2)
z_spec = tbdata.field(3)
halo_id = tbdata.field(4)
dx = tbdata.field(5)
N_sat = tbdata.field(6)
mag = tbdata.field(7)

#Central Redshift histogram:
## set binwidth 
binwidth = 0.01
hist1, bins, patches = plt.hist(cen_z, bins=np.arange(0., max(cen_z) + binwidth, binwidth), facecolor = 'blue')
plt.title('Central Redshift Histogram')
plt.xlabel("Redshift 'z'")
plt.ylabel("Population Density")
plt.show()

#Satellite Redshift histogram:
## set binwidth 
binwidth = 0.01
hist2, bins, patches = plt.hist(sat_z, bins=np.arange(0., max(sat_z) + binwidth, binwidth), facecolor = 'red')
plt.title('Satellite Redshift Histogram')
plt.xlabel("Redshift 'z'")
plt.ylabel("Population Density")
plt.show()

#Satellite Total Histogram
binwidth = 0.01
hist3, bins, patches = plt.hist(z_spec, bins=np.arange(0., max(sat_z) + binwidth, binwidth), facecolor = 'green')
plt.title('Total Redshift Histogram')
plt.xlabel("Redshift 'z'")
plt.ylabel("Population Density")
plt.show()
plt.hist(hist2/hist3, bins, facecolor='green')

I get the following graphs
Central Galaxy Hist

Satellite Galaxy Hist

Total Galaxy Hist

Satellite Fraction Hist

How can I get the satellite fraction as a function of redshift?

Your hist2/hist3 value is already binned.  You don't want to bin it again.  Doing so gets you the distribution of the values of the ratio.  Not what you are looking for.
So as per the pyplot.hist documentation (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html):

If the data has already been binned and counted,
use bar or stairs to plot the distribution

So, try
plt.bar(hist2/hist3)


To show one histogram versus the other, you can first plot the largest and then on top of it the smallest.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# generate some dummy test data
cen_z = np.sin(np.random.rand(200_000) * 30) ** 2 + np.random.rand(200_000) ** 2 + np.random.rand(200_000) ** 3
sat_z = np.sin(np.random.rand(100_000) * 30) ** 2 + np.random.rand(100_000) ** 2 + np.random.rand(100_000) ** 3
z_spec = np.concatenate([cen_z, sat_z])


binwidth = 0.01
hist3, bins, patches = plt.hist(z_spec, bins=np.arange(0., max(sat_z) + binwidth, binwidth), facecolor='green',
                                label='Satellite Redshift Histogram')
hist2, bins, patches = plt.hist(sat_z, bins=np.arange(0., max(sat_z) + binwidth, binwidth), facecolor='red',
                                label='Total Redshift Histogram')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Satelite vs Total Redshift Histogram')
plt.xlabel("Redshift 'z'")
plt.ylabel("Population Density")
plt.show()


To show the ratios, you need a bar plot, using the bins as x-axis. Note that the variable bins contains the edges of the bins: the number of edges is one larger than the number of bins (and the number of entries in hist2 and hist3). The width of the bars needs to be set to the width of the bins. Using np.divide prevents a warning when dividing zero by zero.
plt.bar(bins[:-1], np.divide(hist2, hist3), align='edge', width=bins[1]- bins[0], facecolor='turquoise')
plt.title('Satelite vs Total Redshift Histogram')
plt.xlabel("Redshift 'z'")
plt.ylabel("Ratio of Population Density")
plt.show()


